# How to implement a UICustomSearchBar in a UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need help in implementing UICustomSearchBar in UITableViewController.

Comment: please provide more details... 'plz'

Comment: I have developed a custom address book view ,I retrieved and sorted all contacts in UITableViewController but now I want to implement custom search bar on it so that client can search contacts from it

Comment: what kind of customization you need ?

Comment: I need to put a search bar on tableview and user should be able to search using this search bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ali i would like to suggest you in this situation,that instead of making custom `UICustomSearchBar` drag and drop the `UISearchBar` which contains search Display Controller in your Xib of `UITableViewController` from the library ....and put it above the `UITableView` it will auto adjust himself...reason i am suggest you this is in `UITableViewController` class the whole view is covered by table....so custom `searchBar` will create some problem on that....this is what i analyse and done in my App

Comment: and wot about the functionality of search bar ?

Comment: @Ali u need a searchBar to search the contents of your table isn't it....so after making the connections you can easily do it(like normal searching by calling its delegates) from your table (but also give some name to the table of UITableViewController and connect it in your Xib) try it...even i had done the same